# How do I use SymLogNorm with pyplot.imsave()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

I am plotting a heatmap using matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor().

```
def gen_heatmap_stadtbahn():

    x_axis, y_axis, dist_data, lowest, highest = load_data_stadtbahn()

    # Plotting Heatmap
    plt.pcolor(x_axis, y_axis, dist_data, norm = colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh = 0.3, vmin = lowest, vmax = highest), cmap = "plasma_r", shading = "auto")
    plt.show()
```

[image: Symlog Visualization]

Now I would like export the raw image without the axes around them:

```
    plt.imsave("heatmap.png", dist_data, cmap = "plasma_r")
```

You can save a plot as a raw image quite easily using pyplot.imsave() but unfortunately that does not seem to provide an option to apply Symmetric Log Normalization to the data but can only visualize the data linearly.

[image: Linear Visualization]

Documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html

Is there a way to force matplotlib to use SymLogNorm and if not is there an easy way to have numpys perform this operation on the data? I unfortunately could only find examples of a logarithmic scale which can not handle negative numbers.

Comment: Do you just want the image saved as a pixel for each data point, or were you ok using matplotlib's re-sampling to change the size of the image?  You can easily pass the data through the norm and then get an RGBA array by calling the colormap on the result

Comment: I would like to preserve all pixels because I need this as a mask over an existing map. What exactly do you mean by passing it through the norm (?) and call the colormap on *it*